# CSS Overflow: hidden works at first and then doesn't?

Tags: html, css

For some reason the code below works once, but if I change the height values for .Image, it stops working. The test image overflows instead of being hidden. Then the containing div won't resize no matter how often I try to change height.

```
    .Image{
        background-color:red;
        height:400px; 
        overflow:hidden;    
    }

 </style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
    <div class="Image">
        <img "src="images/test.jpg" alt="test">
         </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you give a working example? because overflow and height should always work

Comment: Please do provide an example jsfiddle of what  won't work, I tested your code and changing the image's height using CSS dosen't seem to reproduce your issue. I would reccomend removing the quotation mark preceding the src, but I assume this was not in your initial code as it stops the image rendering altogether.

Comment: it is working  [check on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htm5L/)

Comment: Okay..so it looks like I was using the wrong comment tags?

In creating a fiddle I stumbled across a comment I had written in the original code next to the .Image height property. I used <!-- --> instead of /* */. If you add <!--COMMENT --> to rrugby's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/htm5L/), it reproduces the problem I was seeing, except sometimes it would work at first, then stop.

So is <!-- --> not allowed in internal style sheets??

Comment: You might not fully understand CSS - <!-- --> is not a valid comment in CSS. Comments in CSS are /* */ - please Edit your question to include a full code example with jsfiddle that consistently fails. Voting to close.

Comment: **`overflow: hidden;` should work as long as you specify a dimension** (which you did). Are you confused about [what `overflow:hidden` does](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/css2/overflow.html)?

Comment: My point is that I realized the problem. I used <!-- instead of /*,  which is what caused the problem. I deleted the comments from the original post because they were just temporary and I didn't think they were the problem. But they were. It's fixed. No use re-posting the fiddle. Close if you want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the reason why is doesn't work is because you have an error in your code at img

```
<img "src="images/test.jpg" alt="test">
```

your error is ->

```
<img "src="...">
```

it should be ->

```
<img src="...">
```

with out the extra quote

so your code should look like this

```
   .Image{
        background-color:red;
        height:400px; 
        overflow:hidden;    
    }

 </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
    <div class="Image">
        <img src="images/test.jpg" alt="test">
    </div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```